# In visual Studio, when formating automatically, how to reduce block spacing to minimum?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, line-spacing

When doing formatting is there an options to control and reduce spaces in blocks ?
[image]

Comment: see tools-->options-->Text Editor-->C#-->Tabs

Comment: @bsmall, Is any update?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to reduce extra blank lines.

First, please use hot key Ctrl+H to open replace function box.

Second, please select the code you want to format.

Third, please choose `Use regular expression` and `Selection`.

[image]

Finally, please input `(?<=\r\n)\r\n` in the find box and click the Replace all.

[image]